# How to number slides in the beamer theme Hannover ?

Tags: beamer

I used the package `beamer outer theme split numbered` to make it for themes with navigation. But the theme `Hannover` is different. Is re-defining the footline the only choice, or is there some other convenient way?

Update: the solutions like

```
\useoutertheme{infolines}
```

or

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
```

can both do the job, but not so grace as I expect. Both of them will ruin the layout of Hannover. It is better to put the page number on the bottom of the left column, or at the left side of the navigation row.

Comment: I don't know about the outer theme `split numbered`.  Do you mean `split`? That doesn't have slide numbers by default.  Do you mean `infolines`?

Comment: @Matthew: I meant this one `beamer_splitnumber` http://sites.google.com/site/shinhsin/beamer_splitnumber

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find a way finally. It is not a light solution, but it looks better.

[image: Hannover with slide numbers]

My code is below. Maybe someone else also need it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title[Hack Hannover]{Hannover with slide numbers}
\author[Beamer]{Beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\def\swidth{1.6cm}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\swidth}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}
{
  {\usebeamerfont{title in sidebar}%
    \vskip1.5em%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in sidebar}%
    \insertshorttitle[width=\swidth,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
    \vskip1.25em%
  }%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in sidebar}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in sidebar}%
    \insertshortauthor[width=\swidth,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
    \vskip1.25em%
  }%
  \hbox to2cm{\hss\insertlogo\hss}
  \vskip1.25em%
  \insertverticalnavigation{\swidth}%
  \vfill
  \hbox to2cm{\hskip0.6cm\usebeamerfont{subsection in
      sidebar}\strut\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in
      sidebar}\inserttotalframenumber-\insertframenumber\hfill}%
  \vskip3pt%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Abel
\item Baker
\item Charlie
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusions}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Abel
\item Baker
\item Charlie
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you only want to have the slide numbers in the footer, I use this (I adapted Matthews code):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Test of Hannover with slide numbers}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Abel
\item Baker
\item Charlie
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For more details on how to modify beamer templates you can also have a look at the [Beamer User Guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

You can install an outer theme on top of a complete theme, as in:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Test of Hannover with slide numbers}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % removes the headline that infolines inserts

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Abel
\item Baker
\item Charlie
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Abel
\item Baker
\item Charlie
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample code]

Comment: Thank you. But since this theme already have a menu part, I'd rather move the information in the infolines there. Is that possible ?

Comment: Anything's possible.  What do you want in the footline?  Just the frame number?

Comment: If the frame number can be moved there, the time stamp, or even logos can also be added there in the same way, right? Whatever,the frame number itself is enough for me now.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you could modify the `beamerouterthemesidebar.sty` to include the current / total frame number right at the bottom of the sidebar.  Here's the relevant diff:

```
--- beamerouterthemesidebar.sty  2018-02-22 02:34:07.000000000 +0300
+++ beamerouterthemesidebarnumbered.sty   2018-12-27 01:29:49.915745978 +0300
 \newdimen\beamer@sidebarwidth
 \newdimen\beamer@headheight
 \usebeamerfont{frametitle}
@@ -151,6 +140,16 @@
     }%
     \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
     \vfill
+    {\usebeamerfont{footline}%
+      \hskip3pt%
+      \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
+      \begin{minipage}[c]{\beamer@tempdim}
+        \begin{center}
+          \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber \par
+        \end{center}
+      \end{minipage}
+      \vskip0.75em%
+    }
     \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
     \else%
       \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
```

[image: outer theme sidebar with page numbering]