# Beamer: footer with current slide number but not total slide number

Tags: beamer, numbering, themes

I am using `infolines` as outer theme and I like it. I would like just to display the current slide number without the total slide number (i.e. instead of "n / N" just "n") in the bottom right corner, keeping the rest of the layout provided by `infolines`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the following post provide a solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13223/how-to-number-slides-in-the-beamer-theme-hannover? That is, using: `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Werner. However, your code inserts JUST a number and deletes the rest of the formatting. I'd like to keep the footer provided by infolines, just instead of having "n/N" I'd like "n"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine set the `footline` beamer template in a way similar to the original definition in the file `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`, but suppressing  `/ \inserttotalframenumber`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you really just want the slide number and nothing else, I found the following solution to be really easy & flexible:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\tikz[overlay]{\node at(12,.25){\thepage};}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This way, you can alter the absolute position of the page number (e.g. add it to the top instead, and so on ...) and add any other information anywhere to the slide, too.