# Appendix in beamer: customizing page format

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, appendices

Here is a simple example of a beamer document. 
Say that I have an appendix called A and an appendix B. In appendix A, I have three slides. This should appear with numbering A.1, A.2 and A.3, while in appendix B, I have two pages. These should appear as: B.1 and B.2

I have done these things so far:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,11pt,mathserif]{beamer} 
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball] 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{easylist}       
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xfrac} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ulsy}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}{Acknowledgement}  
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{criterion}{Criterion}
\newtheorem{findings}{Findings}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .eps}

\author{PSK} 
\title{My title} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{}
The aim of this presentation is to provide insight to 4 papers. These papers talk in general about the following topics: 

\begin{itemize}
\pause
\item Spatial Equilibrium  \\
\pause
\item Inter-temporal dynamics \\
\pause
\item Marine Reserves \\
\pause
\item Exploitation of resources across space
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\section{Brock $\&$ Xepapadeas}

\begin{frame}[label = Brock-Xepapadeas]
They develop a local stability analysis. The problem that they have to solve is                      \hyperlink{model}{\beamergotobutton{here}}:
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item Spatial domain is a circle. 
\item Current value Hamiltonian suggests that negative diffusion means that the movement in space is from low shadow values to higher ones. Authors identify a new mechanism, ODI, used to study pattern formation.
\item They use \textit{LQ approximation} to check the stability of the system.
\item (Main finding): If problem has quadratic payoff, linear transition functions, then the optimal dynamics are unstable.
\item Main target: Analyze the diffusion induced instabilty. 
\end{itemize}

\begin{claim}
Diffusion may act as a stabilizing force when FOSS is unstable. The only way for this to happen is if we have a negative eignevalue.
\end{claim}

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}{}
Critique
\begin{itemize}
\item Possible extension by the introduction of another state variable.
\item Spatial domain can be enriched (\textit{e.g.}, use fractal framework) 
\item The study of diffusion by \textit{kernels}.
\item Use stochasticity 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% Hyperlinks should be placed to appendix

% Appendix part for hyperlinks

\appendix

% appendix frame 1

\section*{Appendix}
\begin{frame}[label = model]
The model: 
\begin{small}
\begin{align}
    \underset{\{u(t,z)\}}{max}\displaystyle  & \int_{z_0}^{z_1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\rho         t}f\left(x(t,z), u(t,z)\right)\,dtdz \\
    \vspace{4mm}
        & \text{s.t.} \quad \frac{\partial x(t,z)}{\partial t} = g(x(t,z), u(t,z)) +         D\cdot\frac{\partial^2 x(t,z)}{\partial z^2} \text{,} \quad x(t_0,z) \, \text{given} \\
\vspace{4mm}
& \text{with spatial boundary conditions} \notag \\
\vspace{4mm}
& (x(t,z_0)) = x(t,z_1) = \bar{x}(t) \text{,} \quad \forall t \, \text{the space is a         circle} 
\end{align} 
\end{small}

Back to \hyperlink{Brock-Xepapadeas}{\beamergotobutton{main}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `etoolbox` package you might try to add this piece of code after the `\appendix` command

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber\hspace*{4ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{app}
\newcounter{framecount}[app]
\setcounter{app}{1}
\setcounter{framecount}{0}
\preto\frame{\refstepcounter{framecount}}
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\Alph{app}.\arabic{framecount}}}
```

The first part between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is to suppress the `/<total number of slides>` thanks to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32815/31058).

In order for it to work you just need to add:

```
\refstepcounter{app}
```

before the `\begin{frame}` command each time you change of Appendix part (from A to B for instance).

Comment: Your code is correct. But I tried with "\setcounter{app}{0}" instead of "\setcounter{app}{1}". Because in the second case it starts with page numbered B.1

Comment: @PSK Are you using `\resfstepcounter{app}` before the first frame of the appendix A? In that case yes you need to start at 0.

Comment: @Ludovic.C Yes, that's right.